NextJS Navigation item not navigating when clicked
I have the following inside my navigation:
import Link from "next/link";

  <Link href='/projects' className="rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white">
     Projects
  </Link>

Also tried without the /
I'm trying to navigate to the projects page

Inside the projects/page.tsx
export default function Projects() {
    return <div>
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
}

However, the nav item will not allow for clicking, I have tried http://localhost:3000/projects and I can see the projects page.
Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?
